# How to pass array of links in to mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a series of links I am interested in scraping using mechanize
Everything works in the following script but I just want to load up each of the link names as an array and then let mechanize do its thing. Ive documented the script so should be self-explanatory.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

agent      = Mechanize.new
#Get the baseline page
agent.get("http://mylink:8080/lablink")
#Get the string for the baseline page to use for later
t="http://mylink:8080"
#Fill out the authentication form
form = agent.page.forms.first
form.j_username = "usr"
form.j_password = "pwd"
form.submit
#Select the project link- level 1

#Create a new array with the text of the projects you are interested in
#Then loop through each project to do what is below:

agent.page.link_with(:text => "TinM_DK").click #I want to have the :text look for an array here
#Select the links that have ViewSample in them- level 2
agent.page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/).map {|link| link.click
    #Select the links that have DownloadFile in them- level 2
    agent.page.links_with(:text => /[1-2]\.fq/).each do |link|
      #Recreate the full URL
    link=t+link.uri.to_s
  #Make string into a qualified URL
  uri = URI(link)
  puts uri
  Save the correct file with fq.gz
  #Get it to download to which ever folder you want by cd into that folder and then paste the code into irb
  agent.get(link).save
end
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to do some work and track down where specifically things are going wrong. Then once you understand the problem, come back and post a specific question with a small piece of code that demonstrates it in a way that can be replicated.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. It is specifically going wrong at the line agent.page.link_with(:text => "TinM_DK").click. I want the :text => to take values from an array and then perform the subsequent code from it. It looks as though it can only take single line text from it.

Comment: Ok, so how about removing all the code that is not necessary to demonstrate what you want and also explain what you mean by :text taking values from an array. It would also be a good idea to show that you at least tried (I don't see an array anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ruby and coding in general. I think I've found a way of saving the urls from the initial crawl as an array. I can upload the code if this would help?

Just looking at a way of calling the urls in the array to parse in the next script.